# Simple ++ doesn't increase number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I propably missing something really simple, but, well, I do. And I can't find it. My code is as follows:

```
    var count = 0;

    $(document).on('click', button, function() {
        var originalLink = button.attr('href'),
            elems,
            count = parseInt(originalLink.match(/\d+$/)[0]),
            cleanlink = originalLink.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''),
            link = cleanlink+''+count;

        $.get(link, function(data) {
            elems = $(data).find(elements);
            $(elems).hide();
            $(elems).appendTo(container);
        }).done(function() {
            count = count++;
            var offsetButton = $(button).offset().top;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: offsetButton
            },500);

            if($('.masonry').length) {
                container.masonry('reload');
                container.masonry('reloadItems');
            };

            $(elems).fadeIn();
        });

        alert(count);

        return false;
    });
```

It should increase `count` with every click. But it doesn't. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Why are you using `alert(count);` outside `.done()`? Note `get` is __async__ call

Comment: IMO `count += 1` or `count = count + 1` would be better.  The second option is actually more efficient according to jsperf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this

```
count = count++;
```

By

```
count++;
```

Doing `count++;` by its own equivalents to doing `count = count + 1;`

While doing `count = count++;` Is the same as `count = count;` because count++ return the value of count before incrementing

You're also resiting count at each click by doing so `count = parseInt(originalLink.match(/\d+$/)[0]),`

You're code fixed

```
var count = 0;

$(document).on('click', button, function() {
    var originalLink = button.attr('href'),
        elems,
        cleanlink = originalLink.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''),
        link = cleanlink+''+count;

    $.get(link, function(data) {
        elems = $(data).find(elements);
        $(elems).hide();
        $(elems).appendTo(container);
    }).done(function() {
        count++;
        var offsetButton = $(button).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetButton
        },500);

        if($('.masonry').length) {
            container.masonry('reload');
            container.masonry('reloadItems');
        };

        $(elems).fadeIn();
        alert(count);

    });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Juhana - you're right. but now it keeps returning `1` all the time ;-)

Comment: Argh! I knew there is a stupid mistake in the code! Right, right.

Answer (score 1):

When the `++` is a suffix, it returns its value *as is* before incrementing the variable.

You should simply use it without explicit assignment.

```
count++;
```

Alternatively, if the `++` was a prefix, it would work (as it would return the value first). However, this would look odd to other developers (due to the explicit assignment being redundant).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned: (3 cases)

1. `count = count++;` returns the **current** value, and **then** increments the number.
2. `count =  ++count` will return the incremented number.
3. where doing `count++;` will just increment the number.

[some fiddle tests to show the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/fpqzykj6/7/)

```
var count=0;
$('#incr1').click(function() {
    count=++count; //why
    $('#res').text(count);    
});
$('#incr2').click(function() {
    count=count++; //wrong
    $('#res').text(count);    
});
$('#incr3').click(function() {
    count++; //better
    $('#res').text(count);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply use `count++` instead of `count = count++`

Answer (score -1):

Explanation:

```
i=i++; //post increment operator

i=0   // intialization
i=i++ // stores value of i and then increments
i=0   //current value of i;
```

try this:

```
i=++i; or i=i+1
```